# nested resource and new form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models Course and Categories

```
resources :categories do
  resources :courses
end
```

A category has many courses and a course belongs to a category.

Currently a user can click on a category and see all the courses from that category, which is what I wanted. However when he chooses to create a new course, that new course is already assigned to a category. I want to give the ability to the users to create a new course and to choose a category from a list, but the current route doesn't allow that.

```
 new_category_course GET    /categories/:category_id/courses/new(.:format)      courses#new
```

I'm not sure what I should do right now to achieve that, any advice would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to give the ability to the users to create a new course and to choose a category from a list, but the current route doesn't allow that.

***Just to clarify that It's only a route, it defines on which controllers action control will go when you hit a url. Your new course is associated with a category inside your action and form***. If you look at your new action you would have something like this:

```
def new
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @category.courses.build #this line makes your course associated with your category
  # if you don't want to associated it with the present category then you can simply do:
  # @category = Category.new
  # and then in your form you can have a select and then assign category to that select
end
```

*In your case you can use rails [**`shallow routes`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) with something like this:*

```
resources :categories do
  resources :courses, only: [:index, :create, :other_actions]
end
resources :courses, only: [:new]
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but since my edit and new forms are different, what's the best way (DRY) to set a form_form(@course) or form_for(@category, @course) without creating 2 different partials. Is there a way to create a conditional based on the controller action ? thanks again

Comment: @BadrTazi no issues :) Can you paste your form? Will be able to help you better. Actually i think you should ask a new question with both forms so that it could help someone else too

Comment: Here's the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851932/conditional-based-on-the-controller-action-for-new-and-edit-forms-in-rails-4 :)