# conditional based on the controller action for new and edit forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form rendered in the new and edit views:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@course, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

Since my edit form should be slightly different: `simple_form_for([@category, @course])`,  is there a way to write a conditional based on the controller action (edit or new) ?

```
# if controller action is new

<%= simple_form_for(@course, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

#if controller action is edit

<%= simple_form_for([@category, @course], html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: rest of fields are same?

Comment: I can only guess how your routes are set up, but if `@category` is nil on the new action, you should be able to use the edit variant for both new and edit.

Comment: @DanielRikowski I was also thinking about it, didn't test it but won't it give a nil error?

Comment: It should't, at least `url_for` works perfectly with arrays containing nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `action_name`

```
<% if action_name == 'edit' %>
  #
<% else %>
  #
<% end %>
```

Or to be really safe, use controller_name also

```
<% if controller_name == 'cources' && action_name == 'edit' %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
- array_object = @course.new_record? ? [@course] : [@category, @course]
```

Or

```
- array_object = action_name == 'new' ? [@course] : [@category, @course]
```

Then do the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for(array_object, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

Read about [new_record?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) helper method